# how to check the length of the local (username) part and domain part in Regular expression for Email in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex, email-validation

The expression i am using currently is

```
"\w+([-+.'!#$%&*/=?^_`{|}~]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "check"? What lengths are allowed and what lengths are not?

Comment: how to validate it,need to restrict it to lets say 10 characters for local and 10 for domain

Answer (score 0):

**This is what i found and it works**

```
^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]{1,64}@(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Za-z]{2,63}$
```

You can find the details in here:
[Email_Regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Test for javascript:

```
var emailRegex = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]{1,64}@(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Za-z]{2,63}$");
emailRegex.test("youremail_notabv_64char@domainname_notexeding63char.domain")
```